# Run a server side Javascript version with Express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

recently i got into web programming and i started to learn javascript,node.js and express.js and my goal is to run a server side javascript function(to be more accurate a function to search something in a mysql db) when a button got pressed on a html.

My dir structure is like this : A main dir, containing a dir "page". Page containing server.js, dbFunctions.js and "public" dir. Public containing a index.html,style.css and some images.

Server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = 8888;

//allow to use static files
app.use(express.static("public"));

//start server

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on port" + port);
```

HTML Example

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test html</title>
 </head>
  <label for="key">Valid key:
   <input id="key" name="key" required>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="testval" checked>
  <button type="button">Button</button>
</html>
```

So basically the HTML got a input field,a checkbox and a button, and if the button is clicked  it should run a function from dbFunctions.js with parameter(taken from the field and the checkbox as bool) **on server side**
I heard something about ajax calls etc but those explanations are usually very confusing. Is there any "hello world" example?

Greetings.

Comment: create your project with `express-generator`, it provides a completed server out of the box.

Comment: I could recommend Sails.js. It is NodeJs, using Express at its core, but much easier to start with. they have excellent boiler plate code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're quite new to JS so I would recommend breaking this down into two components.

One is your server side code and the other is your front end code. As you mentioned you find the front end code confusing, I would suggest coming back to that, once you have got your server side code working.

To make things easy, you could use something like [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) which boiler plates everything for you.

You can then follow [this guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) which will show you how you can set up a route which you will be able to make some sort of request to. Like a POST, GET or PUT request (which is what your front end AJAX code will eventually make a call to).

My advice would be to try get your route working and testing it with something  like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) so you don't have to worry about building the front end simultaneously.

When you are happy with the back end, you can start look into how to make requests from the browser to hit your new back end route you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out this amazing post

https://medium.com/@adnanrahic/hello-world-app-with-node-js-and-express-c1eb7cfa8a30

This is an example hello world node js application with express js.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your html page call your server. To do that you can :

- Place your button inside a form and set your form action equal to `/getHelloWorld`
- Create a javascript script and call your `/getHelloWorld` in [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

In your server you need to catch route like this :

**Server.js :**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = 8888;

//allow to use static files
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/getHelloWorld', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world !');
});

//start server

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on port" + port);
```

with this your server will return *Hello World* When you'r calling this road : `/getHelloWorld`.

Then you just need to replace code inside route catch by a code to call your DB and return your DB response.